# How to populate an object with JSON data from a remote server?

Tags: apex, custom-object, remote-action, crud

I'm new to SF development, my client(who owns the SF account I'm working on) created an object and he wants the JSON objects that I will be sending from a different server through a POST method to be stored in that SF object.

My issues and doubts start on the SF side.
From the little I understood from tutorials and the developers docs, my guess is that I will need to create a Apex class to define the URI and behaviour. Is that right?

Are there any other more Straightforward ways to achieve this(or any other CRUD operation on an object for that matter) without having to use Apex coding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's two routes you can take.

1. Build an Apex REST service. This is covered on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices). You'll write an Apex class and use the `@RestResource` annotation to define an endpoint, along with annotations like `@HttpPost` to route inbound requests to specific methods.
2. Just have your remote system talk directly to the [Salesforce REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart.htm), specifically, to the [sObject Create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm) resource. Then, no code is required.

(1) produces a looser coupling between your remote system and your Salesforce data model, but you have to write code to make it work. It also allows you to write logic specifically to transform inbound data to match the expectations of your Salesforce database.

(2) is more applicable if you want to move rapidly, use a low-code approach, or have a middleware platform that can transform inbound data to meet Salesforce's expectations.